# plugins to integrate jemeter with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Are there any other plugins to integrate Jmeter with Jenkins appart from performance.hpi from the Jenkins web? Is this the best plugging? At least it´s the only one I could find.

Comment: You can leverage command line parameters to integrate JMeter with Jenkins. Please check my blog article on how to integrate JMeter with Jenkins. http://qainsights.com/integrate-apache-jmeter-jenkins/

Answer (score 0):

For the time being [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) is the most reasonable option to use with JMeter on Jenkins.

If for some reason it is not applicable for you you can consider running your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool, this way you will be able to get:

- [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/)-style reports via [JUnit XML Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/), this way JMeter test results will be converted into JUnit format and you will be able to use [JUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) and derivatives (i.e. [Test Results Analyzer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin))
- [Online Interactive Reports](http://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/) - web based report which provides rich information on a variety of metrics and has some extra features like comparing different test executions